# Print an image on python 3.7

Tags: python, image

I am trying to print an image with Python (I use Thonny).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

image_entrée = Image.open("Lenna.png")
image = np.asarray(image_entrée)
nb_lignes,nb_colonnes,_ = image.shape

image_sortie = np.copy(image)

Image.fromarray(image).save("image_entree.png")
Image.fromarray(image_sortie).save("image_sortie.png")
```

This code is coming from a website and I don't understand where I have to put my image.
I tried to change the file name and the image name but nothing changes.
It says that it can not find Lenna.png
In which file do I have to put my .png image ?

Thank you a lot for the time you will give me :)

Comment: program is looking for "Lenna.png" in the same directory where your python program is, one way is copy ""Lenna.png" or any other image you want to use to put in the same folder where your .py program is. the other way is give it as a path `my_file_path=r"/Users/SimpleApp/Downloads/my_picture.png"` and then use `image_entrée = Image.open(my_file_path)`

Comment: It works, thank you so muuuuuuuuch <3

Comment: you are welcome! posted as an answer for future references and you can accept that as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

program is looking for "Lenna.png" in the same directory where your python program is, one way is to copy `Lenna.png` or any other image you want to use to put in the same folder where your .py program is. the other way is give it as a path `my_file_path=r"/Users/SimpleApp/Downloads/my_picture.png"` 
and then use
`image_entrée = Image.open(my_file_path)`